Sharing screen in Teams with fewer steps
I am using Microsoft Teams 06.05.2024 (Version 24091.214.2846.1452) on a daily basis.
To conduct and moderate a Teams call, my workflow is as follows:

Open the Teams appointment
Click on the “attend/participate” button (“Jetzt teilnehmen” in German) with video camera activated
Maximize the resulting window with my video screen, being the first and yet single participant
Open a second window with the meeting minutes on a second screen
Hit the “Share” button on the Teams screen and select the meeting minutes screen opened before
Step 5. results in my Teams window to be shrunk to  81x66 mm² notification window format at the lower right corner of my main screen.
I have to pan and maximize this window to see the full main Teams window again.
This is shown in this related tutorial video. It recommends to maximize the Teams windows by clicking on the task bar. I would prefer to keep it maximized in the first place.
Wait until other participants arrive
Etc. ….

My question:
Can I avoid step 6.? How?
It is just a convenience issue, but I have to go through this step quite frequently.

Why do you need to maximize your Teams window? Is the main issue that when you begin sharing, the Teams meeting UI "un-maximizes" itself?

Yes, the main Teams window gets un-maximized. This does not make sense, as I am using several screens, not just one. I like to have the window maximized to actually see arriving participants.
